# How to insert commas in between the String

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I have format for List of Items as

```
 String[] ByDefalutMessagename = {"Items One, Item two, Item three"};
```

Which gives output as a list of

1. Item One
2. Item two
3. Item three

Now If I would Like to inser "," in between Item two and Item three such that now Output should be like this

1. Item One
2. Item , two
3. Item , three

How can I achieve this???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your first example, there is only one string in the array, not 3

Comment: replace the white space with comma e.g: `ByDefalutMessagename[0].replace(' ', ',');`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below with Java **join** method:

```
String[] strArray = { "Item", "One", "Item", "two", "Item", "three" };

String joinedString = String.join(", ", strArray);
System.out.println(joinedString);
```

**Output: Item, One, Item, two, Item, three**

Hope this helps.

Comment: EDIT: `String.join()` is not specific to Java version 8